# Что вернет submit(), если таск не был успешно добавлен в очередь задач?

Tags: многопоточность, java

У меня создается пул подобным образом:

```
pool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(20),new ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy());
```

Возник такой вопрос: что вернет вызов `pool.submit()`, если будет сабмитится таск по счету больший размера очереди задач, в данном случае 21-ый. Вернет ли он обычный Future, или null. В javadoc сказано, что будет сгенерированно RejectedException, но у меня прописан DiscardPolicy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Из документации:*

> If the task cannot be submitted for execution, either because this executor has been shutdown or because its capacity has been reached, the task is handled by the current **RejectedExecutionHandler.**

`DiscardPolicy` - и есть `RejectionExecutionHandler`, который, цитируя:

> Does nothing, which has the effect of discarding task r

*т.е молча выкинет данный таск.*

Comment: Это понятно. Понятно что произойдет с таском. *НО* вопрос в том что вернет submit() - обычный Future или null может быть  ?

Comment: Полазил по доке, нарыл RejectedExecutionException

Так, что я думаю submit() ничего не вернет, надо ловить Exception.

Comment: Хм, Exception будет если RejectedHandler будет его бросать. У меня выставлен RejectedHandler который просто дропает таск..

Comment: А Вы проверьте (submit()) и опубликуйте результат.

Comment: Попробую..

Comment: Возвратит обычный Future